# question about unity c# script update function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm trying to make a timer to control gameObject display,i found `t` doesn't change when it become zero,
how can i fix it or another better solution?

```cs
public class randomGopher : MonoBehaviour
{

  // Use this for initialization
  public int t;
  public bool active;
  void Start()
  {
    t = Random.Range(30, 150);
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {
        Debug.Log(t);
    if (t == 0)
    {
      active = this.gameObject.activeSelf;
      this.gameObject.SetActive(!active);
      t = Random.Range(30, 150);
    }
    else
    {
      t = t - 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `FixedUpdate`? Be more specific. It is hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: That is because _Unity will no longer call the Update() method of a script attached to a deactivated GameObject._ Consider making a separate script for the timer, attach it to a gameobject that doesn't get deactivated and set the `randomGopher` inactive from there.

Comment: After `gameObject.SetActive(!active);` it is probably inactive and therefore `Update` not called anymore ... what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is that `Update` is not called anymore if the `GameObject` your script is attached to is inactive after

```
gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

---

(Not 100% sure and can't test it right now as typing on smartphone.)

Afaik [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) is still working also on a disabled `MonoBehaviour` or inactive `GameObject` (at least I know that it is the case for `InvokeRepeating`) so you could probably simply use something like

```
public class randomGopher : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Adjust these in seconds
    [SerializeField] private float minDelay = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float maxDelay = 3f;

    private void Start()
    {
         Invoke(nameof(SwitchActiveState), Random.Range(minDelay, maxDelay);
    }

    private void SwitchActiveState ()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(! gameObject.activeSelf);

        Invoke(nameof(SwitchActiveState), Random.Range(minDelay, maxDelay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is executing your script in a separated GameObject, and only activate or deactivate the TargetObject.

```
public class randomGopher : MonoBehaviour
{

  // Use this for initialization
  public int t;
  public bool active;
  public GameObject TargetObj;
  void Start()
  {
    t = Random.Range(30, 150);
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {
    Debug.Log(t);
    if (t == 0)
    {
      active = TargetObj.activeSelf;
      TargetObj.SetActive(!active);
      t = Random.Range(30, 150);
    }
    else
    {
      t = t - 1;
    }
  }
}
```